# Opening HTML source code in Cocoa

Tags: html, cocoa, encoding

I'm trying to display HTML source code in my NSDocument based application. However, it renders the page as Safari would show it.

Here's the code that I use to open HTML:

```
    NSData*data;
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSHTMLTextDocumentType
                                                            forKey:NSDocumentTypeDocumentOption];
    data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[self fileName]];
    mString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
               initWithData:data options:dict documentAttributes:NULL
               error:outError];
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution is a mix of your original code and the bogus solution I gave you in my previous answer (which I've deleted). Use `NSPlainTextDocumentType` as the type, as you were doing originally, but use `initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:`, not `initWithHTML:options:documentAttributes:`.

Alternatively, create a plain NSString holding the source code, and then create an attributed string with that plain string plus whatever attributes you want to apply to the whole document (e.g., fixed-pitch font).